# Accelerating matrix vector multiplication with ARM Neon Intrinsics on Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: c++, raspberry-pi, arm, simd, neon

I need to optimize a matrix vector multiplication. The data looks like following:

- Vector has 81 columns
- Matrix has 90,000 rows and 81 columns and is already transposed. So row-wise dot product can be used.
- The output is hence a vector with 90,000 rows
- All lie in 1D float array

Some non-function requirements are also have to be met for this routine:

- As few as possible standard libraries should be used (no `std::vector` for example)
- No third-party library should be used (so no `Eigen` or `Blas` for me, either)

This is my (simplified, where I assume the input is perfectly blocked, for sake of readability) code,

```
// input_height = 90000
// input_width = 81

for (uint32_t y = 0; y < input_height; y += 4) {
    float32x4_t sum0 = vmovq_n_f32(0);
    float32x4_t sum1 = vmovq_n_f32(0);
    float32x4_t sum2 = vmovq_n_f32(0);
    float32x4_t sum3 = vmovq_n_f32(0);

    for (uint32_t x = 0; x < input_width; x += 16) {
        float32x4x4_t A = load_matrix_transpose(kernel + x);

        float32x4x4_t B0 = load_matrix_transpose(input + y * input_width + x);
        float32x4x4_t B1 = load_matrix_transpose(input + (y + 1) * input_width + x);
        float32x4x4_t B2 = load_matrix_transpose(input + (y + 2) * input_width + x);
        float32x4x4_t B3 = load_matrix_transpose(input + (y + 3) * input_width + x);

        matrix_element_wise_multiplication(A, B0, sum0);
        matrix_element_wise_multiplication(A, B1, sum1);
        matrix_element_wise_multiplication(A, B2, sum2);
        matrix_element_wise_multiplication(A, B3, sum3);
    }

    output[y] = vaddvq_f32(sum0);
    output[y + 1] = vaddvq_f32(sum1);
    output[y + 2] = vaddvq_f32(sum2);
    output[y + 3] = vaddvq_f32(sum3);
}
```

Where the `load_matrix_transpose`, `matrix_element_wise_multiplication` are the following functions:

```
inline float32x4x4_t load_matrix_transpose(float *a) {
    float32x4x4_t ret;

    ret.val[0] = simd_load(a);

    ret.val[1] = simd_load(a + 4);

    ret.val[2] = simd_load(a + 8);

    ret.val[3] = simd_load(a + 12);

    return ret;
}

inline void simd_matrix_element_wise_multiplication(float32x4x4_t & A, float32x4x4_t & B, float32x4x4_t & C) {
    C = vmlaq_f32(C, A.val[0], B.val[0]);
    C = vmlaq_f32(C, A.val[1], B.val[1]);
    C = vmlaq_f32(C, A.val[2], B.val[2]);
    C = vmlaq_f32(C, A.val[3], B.val[3]);
}
```

On my Rasperry Pi 4 (ARMv8, 8GB RAM, 4 cores) the code takes with optimization level `-O3` about `60ms`.

On long run (many loops), the Neon register version is exactly twice as fast as the normal code.

My question is, is there anyway to optimize the code further? I have tried many things but can not make any improvement with respect to the normal code.

Comment: Did you compare to doing the same with a library like Eigen? (compiling with `-O2 -march=native`, optionally also with `-omp`)

Comment: @chtz that is good suggestion. If the performance would be somewhere near Eigen (which I doubt), then I would know it is not feasible to optimize further.

Comment: Why the matrix transpose? It makes sense on small matrices (4x4) to avoid the time consuming 2x`vpadd`, but it gets diminishing on such a big matrix (81x90000). And matrix transpose isn't for free.

Comment: You are way better off with 90000xdot product of 81.

Comment: @Jake'Alquimista'LEE 

"Why the matrix transpose?" that matrix is already transposed on emergence

Comment: @Jake'Alquimista'LEE so instead of 16 multiplications on 4 rows should I do 64 multiplications on one single row?

Comment: I don't know about `emergence` Can you disable the transpose on that? BTW there is absolutely no reason for using`x4` vector types unless you are using `vld4/vst4` `x4` types are meant to be consecutive registers, and you never know how much more mess compilers will generate because of this.

Comment: @Jake'Alquimista'LEE I can not disable the transposing since the matrix already comes like that to me. So the transposing doesn't cost me anything, either. 

  "BTW there is absolutely no reason for usingx4 vector types unless you are using vld4/vst4 x4 types are meant to be consecutive registers, and you never know how much more mess compilers will generate because of this" That is a good hint, I will remove `float32x4x4_t`

Comment: That's too bad. It would run by an order of magnitude faster with the transposing disabled.

Comment: @Jake'Alquimista'LEE How that? I could write another version for the matrix function to give me an untransposed result back. It would take me time, but yours solution sound very promising.

Comment: I just tested my function: it takes 1.4ms on  RK3368 (Cortex-A53)

Comment: @Jake'Alquimista'LEE damn that is sick. I am rewriting my code, at the moment....

Comment: Ok, I'll be posting the answer within a few hours after analyzing the disassembly.

Comment: I corrected a stupid bug, and it takes 10.4ms

Comment: @Jake'Alquimista'LEE that would be still an improvement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Data locality is the highest priority when it comes to optimizations, and you should be aware of the register capacity since registers are BY FAR the fastest and most scarce resource.

`aarch64`: 32x128bit `neon` registers (512 bytes)
`aarch32`: 16x128bit `neon` registers (256 bytes)

A 81x90000 matrix when transposed requires to hold 90000 intermediate values to do the multiplication, and since 360000 bytes don't fit into a register bank of 512 bytes, there will be TONS of memory swapping which translates in HUGE performance hits.
On the other hand, 4*81 bytes of the vector fit nicely into the 512 bytes.

```
void matVecMult81x90000(float *pDst, float *pMat, float *pVec)
{
    register float32x4_t vec0_3, vec4_7, vec8_11, vec12_15, vec16_19, vec20_23, vec24_27, vec28_31, vec32_35, vec36_39, vec40_43, vec44_47, vec48_51, vec52_55, vec56_59, vec60_63, vec64_67, vec68_71, vec72_75, vec76_79, vec80;
    register float32x4_t mat0, mat1, mat2, mat3, mat4, rslt;
    register float32x2_t drslt;
    register uint32_t nRows = 90000;

    vec80 = vdupq_n_f32(0.0f);
    mat4 =vdupq_n_f32(0.0f);
    vec0_3 = vld1q_f32(pVec); pVec += 4;
    vec4_7 = vld1q_f32(pVec); pVec += 4;
    vec8_11 = vld1q_f32(pVec); pVec += 4;
    vec12_15 = vld1q_f32(pVec); pVec += 4;
    vec16_19 = vld1q_f32(pVec); pVec += 4;
    vec20_23 = vld1q_f32(pVec); pVec += 4;
    vec24_27 = vld1q_f32(pVec); pVec += 4;
    vec28_31 = vld1q_f32(pVec); pVec += 4;
    vec32_35 = vld1q_f32(pVec); pVec += 4;
    vec36_39 = vld1q_f32(pVec); pVec += 4;
    vec40_43 = vld1q_f32(pVec); pVec += 4;
    vec44_47 = vld1q_f32(pVec); pVec += 4;
    vec48_51 = vld1q_f32(pVec); pVec += 4;
    vec52_55 = vld1q_f32(pVec); pVec += 4;
    vec56_59 = vld1q_f32(pVec); pVec += 4;
    vec60_63 = vld1q_f32(pVec); pVec += 4;
    vec64_67 = vld1q_f32(pVec); pVec += 4;
    vec68_71 = vld1q_f32(pVec); pVec += 4;
    vec72_75 = vld1q_f32(pVec); pVec += 4;
    vec76_79 = vld1q_f32(pVec); pVec += 4;
    vld1q_lane_f32(pVec, vec80, 0);

    do {
        mat0 = vld1q_f32(pMat); pMat += 4;
        mat1 = vld1q_f32(pMat); pMat += 4;
        mat2 = vld1q_f32(pMat); pMat += 4;
        mat3 = vld1q_f32(pMat); pMat += 4;
        rslt = vmulq_f32(mat0, vec0_3);
        rslt += vmulq_f32(mat1, vec4_7);
        rslt += vmulq_f32(mat2, vec8_11);
        rslt += vmulq_f32(mat3, vec12_15);

        mat0 = vld1q_f32(pMat); pMat += 4;
        mat1 = vld1q_f32(pMat); pMat += 4;
        mat2 = vld1q_f32(pMat); pMat += 4;
        mat3 = vld1q_f32(pMat); pMat += 4;
        rslt += vmulq_f32(mat0, vec16_19);
        rslt += vmulq_f32(mat1, vec20_23);
        rslt += vmulq_f32(mat2, vec24_27);
        rslt += vmulq_f32(mat3, vec28_31);

        mat0 = vld1q_f32(pMat); pMat += 4;
        mat1 = vld1q_f32(pMat); pMat += 4;
        mat2 = vld1q_f32(pMat); pMat += 4;
        mat3 = vld1q_f32(pMat); pMat += 4;
        rslt += vmulq_f32(mat0, vec32_35);
        rslt += vmulq_f32(mat1, vec36_39);
        rslt += vmulq_f32(mat2, vec40_43);
        rslt += vmulq_f32(mat3, vec44_47);

        mat0 = vld1q_f32(pMat); pMat += 4;
        mat1 = vld1q_f32(pMat); pMat += 4;
        mat2 = vld1q_f32(pMat); pMat += 4;
        mat3 = vld1q_f32(pMat); pMat += 4;
        rslt += vmulq_f32(mat0, vec48_51);
        rslt += vmulq_f32(mat1, vec52_55);
        rslt += vmulq_f32(mat2, vec56_59);
        rslt += vmulq_f32(mat3, vec60_63);

        mat0 = vld1q_f32(pMat); pMat += 4;
        mat1 = vld1q_f32(pMat); pMat += 4;
        mat2 = vld1q_f32(pMat); pMat += 4;
        mat3 = vld1q_f32(pMat); pMat += 4;
        vld1q_lane_f32(pMat, mat4, 0); pMat += 1;
        rslt += vmulq_f32(mat0, vec64_67);
        rslt += vmulq_f32(mat1, vec68_71);
        rslt += vmulq_f32(mat2, vec72_75);
        rslt += vmulq_f32(mat3, vec76_79);
        rslt += vmulq_f32(mat4, vec80);

        *pDst++ = vaddvq_f32(rslt);
    } while (--nRows);
}
```

---

Unfortunately, compilers don't play along nicely. (Both GCC and Clang)
The generated code shows some stack swapping on the Vector inside the loop.
Below is the same function in hand written assembly without any stack swapping:

```
    .arch   armv8-a
    .global     matVecMult81x90000_asm
    .text

.balign 64
.func
matVecMult81x90000_asm:
// init loop counter
    mov     w3, #90000 & 0xffff
    movk    w3, #90000>>16, lsl #16

// preserve registers
    stp     d8, d9, [sp, #-48]!
    stp     d10, d11, [sp, #1*16]
    stp     d12, d13, [sp, #2*16]

// load vectors
    ldp     q0, q1, [x2, #0*32]
    ldp     q2, q3, [x2, #1*32]
    ldp     q4, q5, [x2, #2*32]
    ldp     q6, q7, [x2, #3*32]
    ldp     q8, q9, [x2, #4*32]
    ldp     q10, q11, [x2, #5*32]
    ldp     q12, q13, [x2, #6*32]
    ldp     q16, q17, [x2, #7*32]
    ldp     q18, q19, [x2, #8*32]
    ldp     q20, q21, [x2, #9*32]
    ldr     s22, [x2, #10*32]

// loop
.balign 64
1:
    ldp     q24, q25, [x1, #0*32]
    ldp     q26, q27, [x1, #1*32]
    ldp     q28, q29, [x1, #2*32]
    ldp     q30, q31, [x1, #3*32]
    subs    w3, w3, #1

    fmul    v23.4s, v24.4s, v0.4s
    fmla    v23.4s, v25.4s, v1.4s
    fmla    v23.4s, v26.4s, v2.4s
    fmla    v23.4s, v27.4s, v3.4s
    fmla    v23.4s, v28.4s, v4.4s
    fmla    v23.4s, v29.4s, v5.4s
    fmla    v23.4s, v30.4s, v6.4s
    fmla    v23.4s, v31.4s, v7.4s

    ldp     q24, q25, [x1, #4*32]
    ldp     q26, q27, [x1, #5*32]
    ldp     q28, q29, [x1, #6*32]
    ldp     q30, q31, [x1, #7*32]

    fmla    v23.4s, v24.4s, v8.4s
    fmla    v23.4s, v25.4s, v9.4s
    fmla    v23.4s, v26.4s, v10.4s
    fmla    v23.4s, v27.4s, v11.4s
    fmla    v23.4s, v28.4s, v12.4s
    fmla    v23.4s, v29.4s, v13.4s
    fmla    v23.4s, v30.4s, v16.4s
    fmla    v23.4s, v31.4s, v17.4s

    ldp     q24, q25, [x1, #8*32]
    ldp     q26, q27, [x1, #9*32]
    ldr     s28, [x1, #10*32]

    fmla    v23.4s, v24.4s, v18.4s
    fmla    v23.4s, v25.4s, v19.4s
    fmla    v23.4s, v26.4s, v20.4s
    fmla    v23.4s, v27.4s, v21.4s
    fmla    v23.4s, v28.4s, v22.4s

    add     x1, x1, #81*4

    faddp   v23.4s, v23.4s, v23.4s
    faddp   v23.2s, v23.2s, v23.2s

    str     s23, [x0], #4
    b.ne    1b

.balign 8
//restore registers

    ldp     d10, d11, [sp, #1*16]
    ldp     d12, d13, [sp, #2*16]
    ldp     d8, d9, [sp], #48

// return
    ret

.endfunc
.end
```

---

Test results on RK3368:
Clang intrinsics: 10.41ms
assembly: 9.59ms

The compilers didn't perform that bad in this case, but more than often they are unbelievably stupid.  I strongly recommend learning assembly.

Comment: Thanks, I will try out your code and come back after testing

Comment: From 10 seconds to 4 seconds. Amazing. Thank you very much

Comment: To be clear. The naive version takes 21 seconds, yours takes 4 seconds. That is almost 5 as fast. I will take my time and learn assembly.

Comment: The main downside of your version is single accumulator, these `rslt +=` lines create a dependency chain. I’ve reworked your code to use 4 of them: https://gist.github.com/Const-me/c7b80e991b93f8a2d9ac6fb0fd9db878

Comment: GCC 10 did quite good by the way, I don’t think you need assembly for that: https://godbolt.org/z/ajex8e

Comment: @Soonts could you also write your code as an answer of this question?

Comment: @LongNguyen OK, added another one.

Comment: @soonts - `VFMLA` is  a "fused multiply accumulate". I doubt the accuracy will remain the same if you use multiple intermediate values; - `mul` and `mla` can be executed back-to-back without any latency; - in-order cores cannot execute two multiplies simultaneously anyway, and the dependency chain isn't an issue on out-of-order cores, at least in this case.

Comment: @Jake'Alquimista'LEE Independent accumulators improve accuracy of the sum. The best way is usually https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairwise_summation and 16 accumulators is a step in the right direction, slightly better than 4 accumulators (1 vector) in your version. Check the optimization guide I linked in my answer, it says on the OP's CPU the latency of FMA is 7 cycles, but throughput is 1 cycle, this means quite a few in-flight instructions can run in parallel, unless data dependencies serialize them. I wonder how the performance compares in practice. I have a Pi4 but I'm using 32-bit OS.

Comment: @soonts Yes, I've been curious myself about this since quite a long time. Maybe I'll test this soon.

Comment: @soonts the link you gave doesn't take `FMA` into consideration. Having to add 16 float values "inaccurately" harms more than only 4. And I repeat: the less powerful in-order cores such as the Cortex-A53 can execute only one multiply instruction per cycle to begin with, and the latencies are nullified while doing `mla`s over and over. That's what "back-to-back" means.

Comment: Download the PDF and scroll to page 28. Pi 4 has Cortex A72, not A53. The latencies are never nullified, they are fundamental limitations of the chip. Code like `r+=a*b; r+=c*d; r+=e*f; r+=g*h;` can only complete one MLA every 3 cycles (data dependency on accumulator), bottlenecks on latency. Code like `r1+=a*b; r2+=c*d; r3+=e*f; r4+=g*h;` can complete one MLA per cycle because these instructions are independent and the throughput is 1 cycle.

Comment: You won't get anywhere near 3x difference because there're loads there not just compute, but I'd expect a measurable difference.

Comment: I slowly get the feeling that you don't know what's FUSED multiply accumulate. Using multiple accumulators isn't an option to start with. And I highly doubt other stuffs you keep telling. You can give me thousands of links on the spec sheets. You know what? There are TONS of PUBLISHED papers on FFT, and most of them are obsolete because modern architectures behave very differently. Go educate yourself about FUSED multiply accumulate first, and measure the speed and accuracy. Then you can talk to me.

Answer (score 1):

Here’s an optimization of Jake’s answer.

Using 4 accumulators instead of a single one helps because FMA instructions have latency much higher than throughput. According to [Cortex-A72 optimization guide](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/uan0016/a), the latency of `FMLA` instruction is 7 cycles for the complete thing, or 3 cycles when the dependency is on the accumulator (if you wonder what the hell is Q-form and D-form, Q is for 16-byte vectors, D is for 8-byte vectors). The throughput is much higher, it’s 1 cycle, the CPU can run one FMA every cycle.

The following version used 4 independent accumulators instead of a single one, should improve the throughput despite we need 3 extra instructions in the end of the loop to sum the accumulators.

I've also used a few macros to help with repetitive code. Untested.

```
void matVecMult81( float *pDst, const float *pMat, const float *pVec, size_t nRows = 90000 )
{
    // 30 vector registers in total; ARM64 has 32 of them, so we're good.
    float32x4_t vec0_3, vec4_7, vec8_11, vec12_15, vec16_19, vec20_23, vec24_27, vec28_31, vec32_35, vec36_39, vec40_43, vec44_47, vec48_51, vec52_55, vec56_59, vec60_63, vec64_67, vec68_71, vec72_75, vec76_79, vec80;
    float32x4_t mat0, mat1, mat2, mat3, mat4;
    float32x4_t res0, res1, res2, res3;

    vec80 = mat4 = vdupq_n_f32( 0.0f );
    // Load 16 numbers from pVec into 3 vector registers, incrementing the source pointer
#define LOAD_VEC_16( v0, v1, v2, v3 )      \
    v0 = vld1q_f32( pVec ); pVec += 4;     \
    v1 = vld1q_f32( pVec ); pVec += 4;     \
    v2 = vld1q_f32( pVec ); pVec += 4;     \
    v3 = vld1q_f32( pVec ); pVec += 4

    // Load the complete vector into registers using the above macro
    LOAD_VEC_16( vec0_3, vec4_7, vec8_11, vec12_15 );
    LOAD_VEC_16( vec16_19, vec20_23, vec24_27, vec28_31 );
    LOAD_VEC_16( vec32_35, vec36_39, vec40_43, vec44_47 );
    LOAD_VEC_16( vec48_51, vec52_55, vec56_59, vec60_63 );
    LOAD_VEC_16( vec64_67, vec68_71, vec72_75, vec76_79 );
    // Load the final scalar of the vector
    vec80 = vld1q_lane_f32( pVec, vec80, 0 );

#undef LOAD_VEC_16

    // Load 16 numbers from pMat into mat0 - mat3, incrementing the source pointer
#define LOAD_MATRIX_16()                         \
        mat0 = vld1q_f32( pMat ); pMat += 4;     \
        mat1 = vld1q_f32( pMat ); pMat += 4;     \
        mat2 = vld1q_f32( pMat ); pMat += 4;     \
        mat3 = vld1q_f32( pMat ); pMat += 4

    // Multiply 16 numbers in mat0 - mat3 by the specified pieces of the vector, and accumulate into res0 - res3
    // Multiple accumulators is critical for performance, 4 instructions produced by this macro don't have data dependencies between them.
#define HANDLE_BLOCK_16( v0, v1, v2, v3 )        \
        res0 = vfmaq_f32( res0, mat0, v0 );      \
        res1 = vfmaq_f32( res1, mat1, v1 );      \
        res2 = vfmaq_f32( res2, mat2, v2 );      \
        res3 = vfmaq_f32( res3, mat3, v3 )

    const float* const pMatEnd = pMat + nRows * 81;
    while( pMat < pMatEnd )
    {
        // Initial 16 elements only need multiplication.
        LOAD_MATRIX_16();
        res0 = vmulq_f32( mat0, vec0_3 );
        res1 = vmulq_f32( mat1, vec4_7 );
        res2 = vmulq_f32( mat2, vec8_11 );
        res3 = vmulq_f32( mat3, vec12_15 );

        // Handle the rest of the row using FMA instructions.
        LOAD_MATRIX_16();
        HANDLE_BLOCK_16( vec16_19, vec20_23, vec24_27, vec28_31 );

        LOAD_MATRIX_16();
        HANDLE_BLOCK_16( vec32_35, vec36_39, vec40_43, vec44_47 );

        LOAD_MATRIX_16();
        HANDLE_BLOCK_16( vec48_51, vec52_55, vec56_59, vec60_63 );

        // The final block of the row has 17 scalars instead of 16
        LOAD_MATRIX_16();
        mat4 = vld1q_lane_f32( pMat, mat4, 0 ); pMat++;

        HANDLE_BLOCK_16( vec64_67, vec68_71, vec72_75, vec76_79 );
        res0 = vfmaq_f32( res0, mat4, vec80 );

        // Vertically add 4 accumulators into res0
        res1 = vaddq_f32( res1, res2 );
        res0 = vaddq_f32( res3, res0 );
        res0 = vaddq_f32( res1, res0 );

        // Store the horizontal sum of the accumulator
        *pDst = vaddvq_f32( res0 );
        pDst++;
    }

#undef LOAD_MATRIX_16
#undef HANDLE_BLOCK_16
}
```

The assembly generated from that source with GCC 10.1 [looks more or less OK](https://godbolt.org/z/rYhGEG).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230131/discussion-on-answer-by-soonts-accelerating-matrix-vector-multiplication-with-ar).